# Find next available row

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a VBA script in Outlook that attempts to grab information from email items and write it to an Excel file.

I included my full script at the end. Here is a quick outline, where I include the parts that I think might need some work.

```vb
Sub Output2Excel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWkBk As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    ' Setup the Excel Application
    Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName, , False) ' Open the Excel file to be updated
    Set xlSheet = xlWkBk.Worksheets(1)

    ' Loop over all the olMail items in FolderTgt, which is a MAPIFolder type
    RowNext = xlSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' <- This line highlighted by debugger (see below)
    ' Write stuff to Excel like
    ' For
        xlSheet.Cells(RowNext , Col).Value = [Whatever Item I want out of FolderTgt]
        RowNext = RowNext + 1
    ' Next

    ' Done with the loop, now save the file and close things down
    xlWkBk.Save
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    xlWkBk.Close
    Set xlWkBk = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
        
    Debug.Print "All Done"
End Sub
```

When I run this script, it updates my excel file correctly, producing results like:

```
+ - + ------- + --------------- + -------- + - +
| 2 | Sender1 | SomeSubject     | 04/13/17 | 0 |
| 3 | Sender2 | AnotherSubject  | 04/13/17 | 0 | 
| 4 | Sender3 | RE: SomeSubject | 04/13/17 | 0 |
+ - + ------- + --------------- + -------- + - +
```

I can even run it multiple times and it appends to the file without issue:

```
+ - + ------- + --------------- + -------- + - +
| 2 | Sender1 | SomeSubject     | 04/13/17 | 0 |
| 3 | Sender2 | AnotherSubject  | 04/13/17 | 0 | 
| 4 | Sender3 | RE: SomeSubject | 04/13/17 | 0 |
| 2 | Sender1 | SomeSubject     | 04/13/17 | 0 |
| 3 | Sender2 | AnotherSubject  | 04/13/17 | 0 | 
| 4 | Sender3 | RE: SomeSubject | 04/13/17 | 0 |
| 2 | Sender1 | SomeSubject     | 04/13/17 | 0 |
| 3 | Sender2 | AnotherSubject  | 04/13/17 | 0 | 
| 4 | Sender3 | RE: SomeSubject | 04/13/17 | 0 |
+ - + ------- + --------------- + -------- + - +
```

**Here's the problem:**

I open the Excel file to look at the results. I close it without any modifications. Then, I try to run the script again in VBA, and I get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
> Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' failed

The debugger highlights the line

```
RowNext = xlSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

This error happens only when I open the Excel file to check the results. I think the VBA script might be opening and closing the file incorrectly, but the resources I've used indicate that this is the right way to do it.

---

More detailed script:

```vb
Sub Output2Excel()

    Dim FolderNameTgt As String
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim FileName As String

    Dim FolderTgt As MAPIFolder

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWkBk As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    Dim RowNext As Integer
    Dim InxItemCrnt As Integer
    Dim FolderItem As Object

    ' Outlook folder, computer directory, and excel file involved in the reading and writing
    FolderNameTgt = "MyUserId|Testing VBA"
    PathName = "N:\Outlook Excel VBA\"
    FileName = "Book1.xls"

    ' Locate the Folder in Outlook. I've left out some of the details here because this part works fine
    Call FindFolder(FolderTgt, FolderNameTgt, "|")
    If FolderTgt Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print FolderNameTgt & " not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Setup the Excel Application
    Set xlApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName, , False)    
    Set xlSheet = xlWkBk.Worksheets(1)

    ' Loop over all the items in FolderTgt
    RowNext = xlSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For InxItemCrnt = 1 To FolderTgt.Items.Count
      
        ' Set and use the referenced item
        Set FolderItem = FolderTgt.Items.Item(InxItemCrnt)

        ' If the Item is of the olMail class, then extract information and write it to excel
        If FolderItemClass = olMail Then
            xlSheet.Cells(RowNext, 1).Value = RowNext
            xlSheet.Cells(RowNext, 2).Value = FolderItem.SenderName
            xlSheet.Cells(RowNext, 3).Value = FolderItem.Subject
            xlSheet.Cells(RowNext, 4).Value = FolderItem.ReceivedTime
            xlSheet.Cells(RowNext, 4).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
            xlSheet.Cells(RowNext, 5).Value = FolderItem.Attachments.Count
            RowNext = RowNext + 1
        End If

    Next InxItemCrnt
        
    ' Done with the loop, now save the file and close things down
    xlWkBk.Save 'FileName:=PathName & FileName
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    xlWkBk.Close
    Set xlWkBk = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
        
    Debug.Print "All Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Rows by itself refers to the activeSheet in Excel. You need to qualify it: xlsheet.rows.count

Comment: @RichHolton, that solved it. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rows** by itself refers to the activeSheet in Excel. You need to qualify it. Instead of

```
RowNext = xlSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

use

```
RowNext = xlSheet.Cells(xlSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: HUGE Thank you! Saved me another couple hours of debugging.

Comment: Makes my day to help someone. :)