# Outlook Item Change duplication

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

In Outlook, I have a [VBA Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529537/output-to-excel-from-outlook-using-vba) that reads new incoming emails and saves some information to an Excel file and also saves the text body and any attachments into a folder. Now, I want to change my script so that it saves any email with the category "Blue".

So I've modified some parts of here like so:

```
Public WithEvents objMails As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objMails = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objMails_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

    If Item.Class = olMail And Item.Categories = "Blue" Then
        Set objMail = Item
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
....
```

The rest of the code includes details about the saving, none of which was changed from my previously working script, but I've included it here for completeness.

```
...
'Specify the Excel file which you want to auto export the email list
'You can change it as per your case
strRootFolder = "N:\Outlook Excel VBA\"
strExcelFile = "EmailBookTest3.xlsx"

'Get Access to the Excel file
On Error Resume Next
Set objExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Error <> 0 Then
   Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
Set objExcelWorkBook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strRootFolder & strExcelFile)
Set objExcelWorkSheet = objExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Get the next empty row in the Excel worksheet
nNextEmptyRow = objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & objExcelWorkSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Specify the corresponding values in the different columns
strColumnB = objMail.Categories
strColumnC = objMail.SenderName
strColumnD = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
strColumnE = objMail.Subject
strColumnF = objMail.ReceivedTime
strColumnG = objMail.Attachments.Count

'Add the vaules into the columns
objExcelWorkSheet.Range("A" & nNextEmptyRow) = nNextEmptyRow - 1
objExcelWorkSheet.Range("B" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnB
objExcelWorkSheet.Range("C" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnC
objExcelWorkSheet.Range("D" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnD
objExcelWorkSheet.Range("E" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnE
objExcelWorkSheet.Range("F" & nNextEmptyRow) = strColumnF

'Fit the columns from A to E
objExcelWorkSheet.Columns("A:F").AutoFit

'Save the changes and close the Excel file
objExcelWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

'EmailBody
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim FileSystemFile As Object
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileSystem.CreateFolder (strRootFolder & "\" & nNextEmptyRow - 1)
Set FileSystemFile = FileSystem.CreateTextFile(strRootFolder & "\" & nNextEmptyRow - 1 & _
    "\Email_" & nNextEmptyRow - 1 & ".txt", True, True)
FileSystemFile.Write Trim(objMail.Body)
FileSystemFile.Close

'Attachments
Dim ItemAttachment As Attachment
For Each ItemAttachment In objMail.Attachments
    ItemAttachment.SaveAsFile strRootFolder & "\" & nNextEmptyRow - 1 & "\" & _
        ItemAttachment.FileName
Next ItemAttachment

End Sub
```

When I first change an email to "Blue", it seems like this script works perfectly: it populates a new row in the excel file with the information and creates a new folder that holds the text and attachments. However, after a few more seconds, it duplicates the records, so that each email is saved multiple times.

For example, if I do the following:

- Mark Email "Test 5" as Blue
- Immediately after mark Email "Test 4" as Blue

then my excel file looks like

```
+ -------- + -------- + ------------ + ------- +
| Email Id | Category | Sender       | Subject | ...
+ -------- + -------- + ------------ + ------- +
| 1        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 5  | ...
| 2        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 4  | ...
| 3        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 4  | ...
| 4        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 4  | ...
| 5        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 5  | ...
+ -------- + -------- + ------------ + ------- +
```

But I only want it to show those changes once, like this:

```
+ -------- + -------- + ------------ + ------- +
| Email Id | Category | Sender       | Subject | ...
+ -------- + -------- + ------------ + ------- +
| 1        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 5  | ...
| 2        | Blue     | me@email.com | Test 4  | ...
+ -------- + -------- + ------------ + ------- +
```

Any idea what might be happening? Thanks

**Update:**

Same thing happens with all my categories.

I'm using Outlook Version 14.0.7180.5002 (64-bit)

Comment: It seems like `objMails_ItemChange` is triggering every time you set `item` to `objMail`. How about using `objMails_ItemAdd` instead of `objMails_ItemChange`?

Comment: @Tehscript ItemAdd seems to only detect new emails in the inbox, so changing the category doesn't trigger the script.

Comment: @0m3r Version 14.0.7180.5002 (64-bit)

Comment: If you remove Else and exit sub then move your code between if item.class and end if. Does it give you the same result?

Comment: @0m3r Yup, same result

Comment: What is you mark different color category? Does it run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143109/discussion-between-kindatechy-and-0m3r).

Comment: @KindaTechy Do you want a work-around? like removing duplicates?

Comment: @Masoud Ideally, I would like to avoid duplicates altogether. However, if that is not possible, then I would consider removing duplicates as an option.

Comment: I found a working solution, but the code works only the first time you set an email to Blue Category. In other words, if you clear its category, and set it to blue again, code will not work for this time. Does this work for you?

Comment: "objMails_ItemChange" event usually not working good always. why dont you use "Application.NewMailEx Event (Outlook)". I have working code for this let me know if you need that

Comment: Wow! It took me a while but I managed to bypass "run the code only for the first time thing" in my previous post. It runs perfect now. Funny thing is bool operator does not work the other way around. I switched 0s and 1s and it worked. I will post my solution now. This was a challenging question indeed!

Comment: @DivyeshM. I'm not attached to using _ItemChange; that's just what I found to work. Post your Application.NewMailExEvent code and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If ItemChange event triggers, it triggers, nothing you can do about it, unless you change the code behind ItemChange, which is unlikely.

But if you cannot change it, you can always control it. I tried to control it with [LastModificationTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867677.aspx) compared to current time but the trigger is sometimes instant so it did not work out well. Then I tried to control item's [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862196.aspx) which took me sometime to figure out, but eventually it worked. My code works with "Blue Category", so you can change it to "Blue" if it works for you.

Use the following:

```
Dim myProp As Outlook.UserProperty
Set myProp = Item.UserProperties.Find("MyProcess")

If Item.Categories <> "Blue Category" Then
    Debug.Print "Removing Blue Category and reseting Item Property"
    Set myProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("MyProcess", olText)
    myProp = True
    Exit Sub
End If

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem And Item.Categories = "Blue Category" Then
    If myProp Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Categorizing Item to Blue Category"
        Set myProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("MyProcess", olText)
        myProp = False
        Set objMail = Item
    ElseIf myProp = True Then
        Debug.Print "Re-categorizing Item to Blue Category"
        Set myProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("MyProcess", olText)
        myProp = False
        Set objMail = Item
    Else
        Debug.Print "Item has already been processed"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Debug.Print "Wrong category or action, exiting sub."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

instead of this:

```
If Item.Class = olMail And Item.Categories = "Blue" Then
    Set objMail = Item
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Nice script! This definitely works for me. I ended up porting the code over to excel and that's not giving me any issues. But this is great if I ever need to come back to Outlook. Thank you! I still wonder why this event fired multiple times...

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the status flags on these e-mails? If you aren't using those for anything else you can just do something lazy like

```
Private Sub objMails_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

    If Item.Class = olMail And Item.Categories = "Blue" Then
        Set objMail = Item
        If objMail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete Then Exit Sub
        objMail.FlagStatus = olFlagComplete
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

And it will set set the e-mail with the checkmark flag the first time it reads with the blue category (and run your code) then ignore the e-mail every other time. There are plausibly better places to put the code in the first place then ItemChange but I'm not thoroughly familiar with all of Outlook's event callbacks.

Comment: I am also pretty unfamiliar with VBA; doing it this way was just something quick and easy that I found. Thanks for the suggestion. It works, but unfortunately I do use flag status frequently for other purposes.